# Shell Scripting If [ -f ./file ]

Tags: shell

I am learning shell Scripting on my own, and I was investigation how to do the If, and I didn’t understand an example that had:

```
if [ -f ./$NAME.tar ]; then
    //do something
else
    //something else
```

Now I did some experimenting, and I gave NAME the name of a file I had on my directory. When I executed without the -f, it was entering in the else condition, but with -f it enters the //do something condition
So I presume -f is for file. Is this correct? I just couldn’t find information to confirm this.

Answer (score 38):

From `bash` manual:

```
  -f file - True if file exists and is a regular file.
```

So yes, `-f` means file (`./$NAME.tar` in your case) exists and is a regular file (not a device file or a directory for example).