# What does the program below do?

Tags: shell, if-statement, unix, unix-timestamp

What does the program below do?

```sh
if [ -f /tmp/monfichier ]
then
    echo `date "+%Y%m%d" `
fi
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511690/shell-scripting-if-f-file (or use Google as I just did) and `man date`!?

Answer (score 1):

If the file exits then print the date

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining the logic and syntax behind it.

Comment: This **does** answer the question. We can argue whether such basic questions even deserve to be answered though.